# Оформить цитату в html

Tags: html, css, svg

Как сделать кавычки только по контуру, как здесь? [image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Общая реализация есть, только ещё cite по правой стороне нужно выровнять.

```css
blockquote {
  position: relative;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

cite span:first-child {
  color: #aeadad;
  font-style: normal;
}

cite span:last-child {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

blockquote:before {
  color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45px;
  height: 40px;
  color: gray;
  content: "\1F676";
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

blockquote:after {
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  width: 45px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -10px;
  content: "\1F677";
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
<p>«Идеалами, освещавшими мой путь и сообщавшими мне смелость и мужество, были доброта, красота и истина. Без чувства солидарности с теми, кто разделяет мои убеждения, без преследования вечно  неуловимого объективного в искусстве и в науке жизнь показалась бы мне абсолютно пустой»</p>
<cite><span>Автор цитаты: </span><span>Альберт Эйнштейн</span></cite>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: _кавычки только по контуру_ - имеется ввиду не закрашенные?

Comment: @Grundy, скорее всего, так как на картинке не закрашены

Comment: да, именно не закрашенные.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение на `SVG`. Не слишком красиво выглядит, можно поместить `svg` в отдельный файл с соответствующим расширением, затем вставить его в псевдоэлемент в качестве `background`. Толщина, цвет контура кавычек и заливка контролируется с помощью свойств `stroke`, `stroke-width` & `fill`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::before,
*::after {
  content: ""; 
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

blockquote {
  position: relative;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

p {
  float: left;
}

cite {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

cite span:first-child {
  color: #aeadad;
  font-style: normal;
}

cite span:last-child {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

#v1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  background: white;
}

#v2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -11px;
  right: -11px;
  background: white;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: gray;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <svg id="v1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="45" height="45"> 
  <path d="m 6.7214062,18.043076 -0.064156,11.63789 11.1641508,0.04633 V 17.999241 h -5.388526 c 0.671855,-2.799183 1.074695,-5.755547 5.861699,-6.093347 V 8.3228563 l -5.181289,0.038381 C 9.0408261,9.8242298 6.5750743,15.671151 6.7214062,18.043076 Z"/>
  <path d="m 23.821401,17.999241 -0.06416,11.63789 11.16415,0.04633 V 17.955406 h -5.388525 c 0.671855,-2.799183 1.074695,-5.755547 5.861698,-6.093347 V 8.2790215 l -5.181288,0.038381 C 26.140821,9.780395 23.675069,15.627316 23.821401,17.999241 Z"/>
</svg>
  <div class="text">
    <p>«Идеалами, освещавшими мой путь и сообщавшими мне смелость и мужество, были доброта, красота и истина. Без чувства солидарности с теми, кто разделяет мои убеждения, без преследования вечно неуловимого объективного в искусстве и в науке жизнь показалась
      бы мне абсолютно пустой»</p>
    <cite><span>Автор цитаты: </span><span>Альберт Эйнштейн</span></cite>
  </div>
  <svg id="v2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="45" height="45">
  <path d="M 35.527302,19.633139 35.591817,7.9297372 24.364823,7.8831426 V 19.677216 h 5.418858 c -0.675637,2.814941 -1.080745,5.787947 -5.894695,6.127648 v 3.603207 l 5.210455,-0.0386 c 4.09538,-1.471228 6.575012,-7.351062 6.427855,-9.736338 z"/>
  <path d="M 18.108444,19.633139 18.172959,7.9297373 6.945965,7.8831427 V 19.677216 h 5.418858 c -0.675637,2.814941 -1.080745,5.787947 -5.894695,6.127648 v 3.603207 l 5.210455,-0.0386 c 4.09538,-1.471228 6.575012,-7.351062 6.427855,-9.736338 z"/>
</svg>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: а как справа  cite поместить?, а то я маржин пробовал, но при ресайзе окна не ок выглядит.

Comment: @Black Fire `text-align: right`?

Comment: не, так не будет.

Comment: @BlackFire, изменил ответ, добавил обтекание справа

Comment: @St1myL как-то не заметил, прошёл мимо, хороший ответ

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, я их целых 10 минут пытался сделать:)))))